# Code not running outside of loop

Tags: c#, sql, sharpdevelop

EDIT:  I am using SharpDevelop

I am new to C# so the answer may be an easy one...I have some code (below) and the WHILE loop runs just fine.  The problem is that once the processing in the WHILE loop has finished, no more code is executed.  If I put a breakpoint on my 'cn.Open(); line and run the program, I never hit that breakpoint.  If I put a breakpoint on the curly bracket '}' just above the 'cn.Open();' line, the code will stop each time I hit that breakpoint.  I am not sure how to get my additional code to run.

```
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string line = null;
    int i = 0;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Sandbox;Data Source=test");

    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\rl\Desktop\TEST_I~1.CSV");

          while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
          {
                string[] data = line.Split(',');
                if (data.Length > 0)
                {
                      if (i == 0)
                      {
                          foreach (var item in data)
                          {
                            dt.Columns.Add(item.ToString());
                          }
                          i++;
                     }
                 DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                 row.ItemArray = data;
                 dt.Rows.Add(row);
                 }
          }
    cn.Open();
    SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn);
    {
    //            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 0);
    //            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 1);
    //            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 2);
    //            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 3);
    //            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 4);
    copy.DestinationTableName = "Member2";
    copy.WriteToServer(dt);
    }
```

Comment: Right click on solution click Clean , then rebuild the solution and try again. You may also try restarting visual studio.

Comment: Are you sure that the while loop is terminating as expected?  Or perhaps it is crashing and burning - which would explain why you don't get to that breakpoint.

Comment: Cleaned the solution and then rebuilt the solution (JIC), made no difference.  Also, restarting didn't make a difference either.

If my loop is erroring out I should be receiving a message while debugging but I don't.  

I just edited the OP to add that I am doing this in SharpDevelop

Comment: You might want to change the way you use disposable ressources... Also, you might not be using the right while condition. See this StreamReader example : http://bit.ly/1hSTfZg

Comment: Does your program stop, or simply hangs and never exist ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few items you may want to address. These may or may not be related to whatever issue you're having debugging with #develop.

1. Declaring things long before you use them (style guidelines)
2. Not disposing of things that implement `IDisposable` (use `using` statements!)
3. Inner scope block; the `copy` variable is being used in it's own scope for no apparently good reason (I may be wrong, but it could be what's throwing #develop's debugger for a loop)

Instead, your code should be closer to this:

```
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    // You may want to pass other parameters to OpenText for read mode, etc.
    using (var sr = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\rl\Desktop\TEST_I~1.CSV"))
    {
        var first = true;
        string line = null;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] data = line.Split(',');
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(item.ToString());
                    }
                    first = false;
                    // Don't add the first row's data in the table (headers?)
                    continue; 
                }
                var row = dt.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = data;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }

    using (var cn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
        {
            // copy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 0);
            // copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 1);
            // copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 2);
            // copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 3);
            // copy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 4);
            copy.DestinationTableName = "Member2";
            copy.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It also looks like OP is creating a column for every item from the split, for *every* line....which might be by design, though I'd expect a uniform number of columns declared before adding the data.

Comment: I think that's what the `i` or `first` (as I have it) check is for. It's reading a header line or something and defining the columns based on it. That said, I'm not sure they'd want the header names to be added as an actual data row. I would maybe add a `continue` after `first = false;` here.

Comment: Ah...didn't catch that part.  Multi-tasking too many things :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit odd but it looks like it should work. There's probably a file lock either making you run against old builds or hang on the .csv open line.

[Cory's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340494/1143) for tidying the code are rather good.

Answer (score -3):

I think you have an infinite loop going on because your `while` check isn't quite right.  You're asking if `line = sr.ReadLine()` is null, not if `line` is null.  The result of setting `line` to the result of the read function will never return null.

Comment: `ReadLine()` returns "The next line from the input stream, or null if the end of the input stream is reached." [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) The result of an assignment operation is the value assigned to the left operand.

Comment: Yes, and they're setting that to the variable called line.  The boolean check, then is looking at whether or not line was able to be set, not at the value that it contains.

Comment: In C#, the result of an assignment is not a true/false as to whether it could be set, it's the value assigned to the left operand (comment edited above).

Comment: Following what @Cory said, `while ((line = null) != null){}` terminates immediately.